# How to adjust hint properties of a control at runtime?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, hints

I have this code with which I can set the font size of the control hint, but I want to be able somehow to adjust it later at runtime. How can I do that ?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TMyHintWindow = class(THintWindow)
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TMyButton = class(TButton)
  protected
    procedure CMHintShow(var Message: TCMHintShow); message CM_HINTSHOW;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    MyButton: TMyButton;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 MyButton:=TMyButton.Create(Form1);
 MyButton.Parent:=Form1;
 MyButton.Caption:='Test';
 MyButton.Left:=100;
 MyButton.Top:=100;
 MyButton.ShowHint:=true;
end;

procedure TMyButton.CMHintShow(var Message: TCMHintShow);
begin
 inherited;
 Message.HintInfo.HintWindowClass:=TMyHintWindow;
 Message.HintInfo.HintStr:='My custom hint';
end;

constructor TMyHintWindow.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
 inherited;
 Canvas.Font.Size:=25;
end;

end.
```

Comment: You execute `Font.Size:=SomeValue` at some later time. Presumably it should be `Font.Size` rather than `Canvas.Font.Size`.

Comment: `Font.Size` of wich component ?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please post a code ?

Comment: No. I don't know when you want to trigger a change. I guess what is tricky is that the hint window instance is not created by you and it's hard for you to find it. You are probably right to use `Canvas.Font` though. You can probably search through the components owned by `Application` to find the instance.

Comment: Or, you could take advantage of the fact that there is only ever one hint window instance. Declare a global variable of type TMyHintWindow. In the constructor, assign to that variable the reference of the new object. In the destructor, assign `nil`. When you need to change the font, you can gain access to the instance that way.

Comment: This might get you started http://pastebin.com/cjD1yfWn.

Comment: I run the code and nothing happened. The hint appears in it's default font size. I assigned new values to `FMyHintData.FontSize` but nothing is changed.

Comment: There is another option to consider - derive a new component from `TCustomHint` and override its virtual `PaintHint()` method, then assign an instance of this component to the button's `CustomHint` property (`CM_HINTSHOW` is not issued when `TCustomHint` is used). `PaintHint()` is given a `TCustomHintWindow` object as input, which you can customize as needed. Have your `TCustomHint` component expose its own `Font` property that you can assign whenever you need to, and then `PaintHint()` can assign its current `Font` to the `Canvas.Font` of the provided `TCustomHintWindow`.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is only one hint window instance at the time, and that instance will be created after call to `CMHintShow`, you can use class variables to do additional hint customization. [Class variable](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Fields) is class member that is shared among all instances of the class and can be accessed directly through class type or class instance.

```
type
  TMyHintWindow = class(THintWindow)
  protected
    class constructor ClassCreate;
  public
    class var FontSize: integer;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

class constructor TMyHintWindow.ClassCreate;
begin
  FontSize := 25;
end;

constructor TMyHintWindow.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Canvas.Font.Size := FontSize;
end;
```

and then you can change `FontSize` in `CMHintShow` method

```
procedure TMyButton.CMHintShow(var Message: TCMHintShow);
begin
  inherited;
  TMyHintWindow.FontSize := 12;
  Message.HintInfo.HintWindowClass := TMyHintWindow;
  Message.HintInfo.HintStr := 'My custom hint';
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from indications given by **TLama** I finally solved this problem. The key was to set `Canvas.Font.Size` in `TMyHintWindow.CalcHintRect`.

Here is the code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TMyHintData = record
    FontSize: Integer;
  end;

  TMyHintWindow = class(THintWindow)
  public
    function CalcHintRect(MaxWidth: Integer; const AHint: string; AData: TCustomData): TRect; override;
  end;

  TMyButton = class(TButton)
  private
    procedure CMHintShow(var AMessage: TCMHintShow); message CM_HINTSHOW;
  public
    FMyHintData: TMyHintData;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    MyButton: TMyButton;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TMyButton(Sender).FMyHintData.FontSize:=44;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 MyButton:=TMyButton.Create(Form1);
 MyButton.Parent:=Form1;
 MyButton.Caption:='Test';
 MyButton.Left:=100;
 MyButton.Top:=100;
 MyButton.ShowHint:=true;
 MyButton.OnClick:=Button1Click;
end;

function TMyHintWindow.CalcHintRect(MaxWidth: Integer; const AHint: string; AData: TCustomData): TRect;
begin
 Canvas.Font.Size:=TMyHintData(AData^).FontSize;
 Result:=inherited;
end;

constructor TMyButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
 inherited;
 FMyHintData.FontSize:=25;
end;

procedure TMyButton.CMHintShow(var AMessage: TCMHintShow);
begin
 inherited;
 AMessage.HintInfo.HintData:=@FMyHintData;
 AMessage.HintInfo.HintWindowClass:=TMyHintWindow;
 AMessage.HintInfo.HintStr:='My custom hint';
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnShowHint:=AppOnShowHint;
end;

procedure TForm1.AppOnShowHint(var HintStr: string; var CanShow: Boolean; var HintInfo: THintInfo);
begin
  {Use HintInfo (type:THintInfo) to specify some property of hint-window}
  {For example: set hint-window width to the width of longest word in the hint-text}
  HintInfo.HintMaxWidth:=1;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {Set HintFont at runtime}
  Screen.HintFont.Size:=strtoint(Edit1.Text);
  {It's necessary to recreate the Application.FHintWindow private variable, so:}
  Application.ShowHint:=False;
  Application.ShowHint:=True;
end;
```